# Can you see my code? This is right? Delivery is not working. Please help me

Tags: android

In next, my code:

Note: I have success when i send, but not trigger when the another mobile receiver.
So, i know only when my sms is sent, but i never know when my sms is delivered on another emulator.

I'm from Brazil, so sorry about the english. I'm still trying learn, laughs...

So, i hope you can help me, more next you can see my code.

My code:

```
private static final String SENT  = "SMS_SENT";
private static final String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

private void enviaMensagem(String numero, String texto, int id){
        try{
            ID_SMS = id;
            PendingIntent sendPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
            PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);


        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                switch(getResultCode()){
                case Activity.RESULT_OK: atualizaStatus("Mensagem Enviada", "envio", ID_SMS);break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE: atualizaStatus("Erro no envio da mensagem", "envio", ID_SMS); break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE: atualizaStatus("Sem serviço", "envio", ID_SMS); break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU: atualizaStatus("ErroO de PDU", "envio", ID_SMS); break;
                }

            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                switch(getResultCode()){
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:atualizaStatus("Mensagem entregue", "recebimento", ID_SMS);break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:atualizaStatus("Mensagem não entregue", "recebimento", ID_SMS);break;
                }

            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
        sMessage = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sMessage.sendTextMessage(numero, null, texto, sendPI, deliveredPI);
        txtStatus.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        txtStatus.setText("Mensagem enviada.");
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            txtStatus.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            txtStatus.setText(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Thanks everybody for everything. Bye.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your intent filter might have the wrong action.  According to this [site](http://www.anddev.org/recognize-react_on_incoming_sms-t295.html) the action name is SMS_RECEIVED.